xcharter font and mathrm
I am using fontsetup with a serif and sans-serif font of my choice to properly typeset different parts of my document, including extensive math usage. There seems to be an issue somewhere in the background with xcharter specifically. Here is my minimum example, where the following four commands should always look the same in the PDF:
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[xcharter]{fontsetup}

\begin{document}
   Teste Schriftartensetup für \emph{XCharter}
      \begin{equation*}
         \sin \mathrm{sin} \operatorname{sin} \text{sin}
      \end{equation*}
\end{document}

But LaTeX seems to default back to Computer Modern, when I call for mathrm:

Thankful for any help!

Welcome to TeX.SE!

Do you have to use the fontsetup package? Otherwise try \usepackage{unicode-math} \setmainfont{XCharter} \setmathfont{XCharter Math}  https://i.sstatic.net/82yVxkrT.png

I'd do \usepackage{xcharter-otf}, instead; fontsetup does several suspicious things.

The Users egreg and samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz suggested that fontsetup may cause multiple problems in the background. I went to using unicode-math standalone as they said, setting main and sans fonts myself. This still didnt resolve all of my issues. The option mathrm=sym seems to do the trick, so now it works as intended.
\documentclass[paper=A5]{scrartcl}

    \usepackage{amssymb}
    \usepackage[mathrm=sym]{unicode-math}
    \setmainfont{XCharter}
    \setmathfont{XCharter Math}

    \setsansfont{Fira Sans Book}[Scale =  .97]
    \setmathfont[version=sans,Scale =  .97]{Fira Math}

    \usepackage{siunitx}
        \sisetup{
            mode = match, 
            propagate-math-font = true,
            reset-math-version = false, 
            reset-text-family = false,
            reset-text-series = false, 
            text-family-to-math = true,%test
            text-series-to-math = true,%test
                output-decimal-marker={,},
            group-digits = all,
            exponent-product = \cdot}

\begin{document}

    Teste Schriftartensetup für \emph{XCharter}
        \begin{equation*}
            \sin \mathrm{sin} \operatorname{sin} \text{sin} \qty{1,4e-2}{\kilogram}
        \end{equation*}

    \sffamily
    \mathversion{sans}

    Teste Schriftartensetup für \emph{Fira}
        \begin{equation*}
            \sin \mathrm{sin} \operatorname{sin} \text{sin} \qty{1,4e-2}{\kilogram}
        \end{equation*}
\end{document}

Funnily enough a different document with a similar setup using fontsetup in the preamble went from looking good to completely destroying one of the fonts within 24 hours, with (as far as I'm aware) no changes to the code! It was also resolved by using the method above.

I would load xcharter-otf instead.
I also add the settings for sans serif and monospaced that fontsetup does when called with the xcharter option; feel free to change the fonts.
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{xcharter-otf}

\setsansfont{CabinCondensed}[
  Scale=MatchLowercase,
  Extension=.otf,
  UprightFont=*-RegularCondensed,
  ItalicFont=*-ItalicCondensed,
  BoldFont=*-SemiBoldCondensed,
  BoldItalicFont=*-SemiboldItalicCondensed,
  SlantedFont=*-RegularCondensed,
  BoldSlantedFont=*-SemiBoldCondensed,
  SlantedFeatures={FakeSlant=0.25},
  BoldSlantedFeatures={FakeSlant=0.25},
  SmallCapsFeatures={Numbers=OldStyle},
]
\setmonofont{Inconsolatazi4}[
  Scale=MatchLowercase,
  Extension=.otf,
  UprightFont=*-Regular,
  BoldFont=*-Bold,
  SlantedFont=*-Regular,
  BoldSlantedFont=*-Bold,
  SlantedFeatures={FakeSlant=0.25},
  BoldSlantedFeatures={FakeSlant=0.25},
]

\begin{document}

Teste Schriftartensetup für \emph{XCharter}

$\sin \mathrm{sin} \operatorname{sin}$ sin

math: $\mathrm{efficient}$

sym: $\symrm{efficient}$

Teste \textsf{Teste} \texttt{Teste} Teste

\textit{Teste \textsf{Teste} \texttt{Teste} Teste}

\textsl{Teste \textsf{Teste} \texttt{Teste} Teste}

\textbf{Teste \textsf{Teste} \texttt{Teste} Teste}

\end{document}

As you see, no special setting has to be done for \mathrm and so it and \symrm remain distinct, as shown in the (contrived) example.

